# How to set values to nullable struct members

Tags: c#, struct

I have this code:

```
public IfStatement? m_IfStatement;

public struct IfStatement
{
    public string Statement { get; private set; }
    public string Comparison { get; private set; }
    public string ConditionValue { get; private set; }
    public string IfCondition_True { get; private set; }
    public string IfCondition_False { get; private set; }
}
```

and when I'm trying to set values to the struct like this:

```
m_IfStatement = new IfStatement();
m_IfStatement.Statement = cboIfStatement.SelectedItem.ToString();
m_IfStatement.Comparison = cboComparison.SelectedItem.ToString();
m_IfStatement.ConditionValue = txtIfValue.Text;
m_IfStatement.IfTrue = "";
m_IfStatement.IfFalse = "";
```

I'm getting this error by the compailer:

```
'System.Nullable<Core.BaseControls.IntegrationTool.frmDataManipulation.IfStatement>' 
does not contain a definition for 'Statement' and no extension method 'Statement' 
accepting a first argument of type 
'System.Nullable<Core.BaseControls.IntegrationTool.frmDataManipulation.IfStatement>' 
could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What does it mean ? and how do I solve this...? please.
Both statements are in the same scope (e.g. in the same class).

Comment: you have kept set as `private`

Comment: Since you defined it as a nullable type, you have to use `m_IfStatement.Value.Statement` and also a public setter. But why use **nullable** anyway? Since a struct cannot be `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since structs are value-types (and therefore cannot be null) and you want it be nullable, you should create a constructor to set the properties. This way you can keep your properties with private setters.

```
public struct IfStatement {
    public IfStatement (string statement, string comparison, string conditionValue, string ifCondition_True, string ifCondition_False) {
        Statement = statement;
        Comparison = comparison;
        ConditionValue = conditionValue;
        IfCondition_True = ifCondition_True;
        IfCondition_False = ifCondition_False;
    }

    public string Statement { get; private set; }
    public string Comparison { get; private set; }
    public string ConditionValue { get; private set; }
    public string IfCondition_True { get; private set; }
    public string IfCondition_False { get; private set; }
}
```

And use it like

```
m_IfStatement = new IfStatement(
    cboIfStatement.SelectedItem.ToString(),
    cboComparison.SelectedItem.ToString()
    txtIfValue.Text,
    "",
    ""
);
```

This will prevent any trouble you have setting a property of a nullable struct.

Answer (score 1):

`Nullable` types access with `Value` property. [Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)

```
 public IfStatement? m_IfStatement;

    public struct IfStatement
    {
        public string Statement { get; set; }
        public string Comparison { get; set; }
        public string ConditionValue { get; set; }
        public string IfCondition_True { get; set; }
        public string IfCondition_False { get; set; }
    }

        m_IfStatement = new IfStatement();
        IfStatement ifStat = m_IfStatement.Value;
        ifStat.Statement = cboIfStatement.SelectedItem.ToString();
        ifStat.Comparison = cboComparison.SelectedItem.ToString();
        ifStat.ConditionValue = txtIfValue.Text;
        ifStat.TrueCondition = "";
        ifStat.FalseCondition = "";
```

Comment: I tried this also, and this get a nother error: Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Nullable<Core.BaseControls.IntegrationTool.frmDataManipulation.IfStatement>.Value' because it is not a variable

Comment: @MuhammadUmar The statement `ifStat = m_IfStatement.Value` creates a copy of the object (since it is a struct), so the values saved into your `ifStat` variable are only changed there, not in the original object.

Answer (score 0):

In your first section you have this:

```
public string Statement { get; private set; }
```

and your second

```
m_IfStatement.Statement = cboIfStatement.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

The second section you are setting Statement, which you have defined in your first that you can only do within the struct itself (i.e. marking it as private).

To fix this, simply change your definition(s) to read:

```
public string Statement { get; set; }
```

Comment: I tried it, it's not that. Both statements are in the same scope